# XDocument C# Join

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have to use joins for the below xml using XDocument

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Name id="1">Test</Name>
        <CardNo>1234</CardNo>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name id="1">Test</Name>
        <CardNo>5678</CardNo>
    </Book>
    <Library>
        <RackNo>4</RackNo>
        <SampleData>Hello</SampleData>
        <CardNo>1234</CardNo>
    </Library>
    <Library>
        <RackNo>5</RackNo>
        <SampleData>John</SampleData>
        <CardNo>5678</CardNo>
    </Library>
</Books>
```

In the above sample I need to join the CardNo but they are present under two different Records.. i.e Library and Book.
I'm using this code but the join doesn't work for XDocument.
Any suggestions please?

```
 var bookRecords = from c in doc.Element("Books").Element("Book")
                   select new { bookCardNo = c.Attribute("CardNo").Value }

var LibraryRecords = from d in doc.Element("Books").Element("Library")
                   select new { libCardNo = d.Attribute("CardNo").Value }

var groupedRecords = 
    from br in bookRecords
    join lr in LibraryRecords 
    on br.bookCardNo equals lr.libCardNo
    select new { rackno = lr.Element("RackNo").Value }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're querying for *multiple* elements, so you want `Elements` and not `Element`. `Element` will only return the first item, so your LINQ expression won't compile.

Secondly, there is no *attribute* called `CardNo` - `CardNo` is an *element*.

And finally, `LibraryRecords` will contain a bunch of anonymous objects. If you want to access `RackNo`, or any other property, you will need to include their values as a property of that object.

```
var bookRecords =
    from book in doc.Elements("Books").Elements("Book")
    select new
    {
        Name = (string) book.Element("Name"),
        CardNo = (string) book.Element("CardNo")
    };

var libraryRecords =
    from lib in doc.Elements("Books").Elements("Library")
    select new
    {
        CardNo = (string) lib.Element("CardNo"),
        RackNo = (string) lib.Element("RackNo"),
    };

var groupedRecords =
    from br in bookRecords
    join lr in libraryRecords
    on br.CardNo equals lr.CardNo
    select new
    {
        br.Name,
        lr.RackNo
    };
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zVZlQz) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are at the same level than books according to the xml schema you show, it'll be easier if you use `Descendants` method, and instead of use `Attribute`, use `Element` because `CardNo` is not an attribute in both cases:

```
var bookRecords = from c in doc.Descendants("Book")
                   select new { bookCardNo = c.Element("CardNo").Value };

var LibraryRecords = from d in doc.Descendants("Library")
                     select new { libCardNo = d.Element("CardNo").Value,
                                  rackno = d.Element("RackNo").Value  };

var groupedRecords = 
    from br in bookRecords
    join lr in LibraryRecords 
    on br.bookCardNo equals lr.libCardNo
    select lr.rackno;
```